# Unable to insert records in ms sql database using android

Tags: android, image, activerecord, ftp, insert

I am trying to upload images to web folder using ftp and it works fine but when i try to insert the records for the corresponding images it is not working and the program gets jumps before try block.**I have used for each loop to upload images as well as to get the file name of the image.** Below is the code which is used to insert as well as upload images.
  So when i try to upload more than 10 images using for each loop i can't able to insert the records but the ftp image uploading works fine.
  I need to know where i have done mistake can anyone pls tell me where i have done mistake.

```
public class DisplayImageActivity extends Activity{
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
String call, db, un, passwords;
String orig;
String names;
String icore;
String imagename;
Connection con;
ResultSet rs;
ConnectionClass connectionclass;
String imagenametag;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection ConnectionHelper(String user, String password,
                                    String database, String server) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + database + ";user=" + user
                + ";password=" + password + ";";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
            .parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    connectionclass = new ConnectionClass();
    call = connectionclass.getip();
    un = connectionclass.getun();
    passwords = connectionclass.getpassword();
    db = connectionclass.getdb();

//    connect = ConnectionHelper(un, passwords, db, call);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/JCG Camera";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();



        orig = "/site1/Image/";

    for(File file1:files){
        imageAdapter.add(file1.getAbsolutePath());
        if(!file1.isFile())continue;
        String msg = "";
        String[]bits=file1.getName().split("_");
      //  imagenametag = file1.getName();
       // String[] parts = imagenametag.split("_");
        names = bits[0];
        icore = bits[1];
        imagename = file1.getName();
        try {
            con = ConnectionHelper(un, passwords, db, call);
            if (con == null) {
                msg = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                String commands = "Insert into Image(Image_Tag,Image_Name,orig_img_path) values ('" + names + "','" + imagename + "','" + orig + "')";
                PreparedStatement preStmt = con.prepareStatement(commands);
                preStmt.executeUpdate();
                msg = "Info Saved";

                    new FTPFileUpload(this).execute(
                            FTPConstants.SERVER,
                            FTPConstants.USER_NAME,
                            FTPConstants.PASSWORD,
                            file1.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/site1/Image/" + file1.getName());
            }
        } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ec) {
            msg = "Image Taken Already";
        } catch (IOError ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            msg = ex.getMessage().toString();
            Log.d("skool", msg);
        } catch (AndroidRuntimeException ex) {
            msg = ex.getMessage().toString();
            Log.d("skool", msg);

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            msg = ex.getMessage().toString();
            Log.d("skool", msg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //    msg= ""+spstud.getSelectedItem()+"'s Record has been saved already for"+date.getText().toString()+"";
            Log.d("skool", msg);
        }
        Toast.makeText(DisplayImageActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/JCG Camera";

  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        file.delete();

    }
    Intent i=new Intent(DisplayImageActivity.this,ListMain.class);
    startActivity(i);
    DisplayImageActivity.this.finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when you try and insert more than 10 images? do you get errors? crashes? Exceptions?

Comment: while inserting more than 10 images the images gets uploaded finely but the insert query doesn't works.and the loop gets jumped before the try block.even to upload 2 images the insert query doesn't works

Comment: Throw in some break points around the SQL area. The fact your images all upload suggests the loop is working fine and your SQL block is t throwing out an exception (otherwise the loop for the images would be broken). To rule out your SQL string itself, try using it directly on the server and see if errors are thrown

Comment: I did't get u can u explain it with some example

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: where i have to set the break points

Comment: `preStmt.executeUpdate()` to start with, then check your variables are being passed correctly to the SQL query. If you only do a single insert, does it work properly?

Comment: yes when i do a single insert it works properly and when i set the break point it shows Datatruncation and  here is the log file what i received

Comment: 11-04 13:25:41.082  10502-10502/nidhinkumar.pencilruler W/System.err﹕ java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation